# Consulta a Firebase en cada ciclo de un array map

Tags: array, firebase, reactjs, react-native, map

tengo un array y lo recorro con un map para renderizar algunos componentes

```
const list = [{'id':1,'name':'a'},{'id':2,'name':'b'},{'id':3,'name':'c'}]

list.map(item=>{
  return <Item key={item.id}/>
})
```

Esto me funciona perfecto. Pero ahora necesito hacer una consulta a firebase en cada ciclo del map, y mandar el resultado de esa consulta

```
list.map(item=>{

  let firebasedata=[]
  var ref = database.ref('example');
  //acá hago la consulta a Firebase por cada cíclo del map, me devuelve un array y lo guardo en firebasedata para enviarlo como props en cada <Item/>

  ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(item.id).on('value', snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(x=> {
      firebasedata.push(x.val())
    }); 
    console.log(firebasedata) //acá me muestra cada array de cada consulta en los ciclos
  });

  console.log(firebasedata) //pero acá sólo obtengo arrays vacíos, y al momento de enviarlo como props en el return del <Item/> también llega vacío el array

  return <Item key={item.id}  firebasedata={firebasedata}/>  //firebasedata está vacío por cada <Item/>
})
```

Cómo podría realizar la consulta en cada iteración del map y enviar esa respuesta a cada  como props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera sencilla de hacerlo sería mediante RxJs. Firebase provee una librería para usar RxJs con Firebase, llamada [rxfire](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/rxfire). Esta librería te permite obtener los documentos y convertirlos a **Observables**, de manera que puedes transformar los documentos a tu gusto.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { doc } from 'rxfire/database'
import { of } from 'rxjs'
import { map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { database } from '../../utils/firebase'

const UsersList = ({ rawList }) => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const usersRef = database.ref('example').orderByChild('id')
    // creamos un observable a partir de la lista
    of(rawList)
      // la transformamos para obtener solos los ids
      .pipe(map(item => item.id))
      // volvemos a transformar la lista
      .pipe(
        // iteramos los ids y usamos cada id para encontrar al documento
        // y devolver el observable con su data (el array de c/snapshot)
        mergeMap(id => (
          doc(usersRef.equalTo(id))
            .pipe(
              map(snapshot => snapshot.val())
            )
        ))
      )
      // por último nos subscribimos para obtener los
      // datos planos (ya no observables)
      .subscribe(users => setUsers(users))
  })

  return (
    <ul>
    { users.map(user => (
        <li>{user.name}</li>
      ))
    }
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Otra opción es iterar la lista por medio de un `for of`, buscar el documento y guardarlo en una promesa; de manera que tengas un array de promesas.

```
const usersPromises = []
for (const item of list) {
  usersPromises.push(
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      usersRef
       .orderByChild('id')
       .equalTo(item.id)
       .on('value', snapshot => {
         resolve(...(snapshot.map(s => s.val()))
       })
}
Promise
  .all(usersPromises)
  .then(users => setUsers(users)
```

Comment: Estoy intentando la segunda opción, la del for. Pero en el resolve me da error diciendo que snapshot.map no es una función, el snapshot me está devolviendo un objeto, en cada iteración del for al ir a firebase, me devuelve algo parecido a esto:

`{
   "1":
      {"id":1,"nombre":"A"},
   "2":
     {"id":2,"nombre":"B"},
   "3":
     {"id":3,"nombre":"C"}
}`

Comment: Ahora me funcionó, en el resolve sólo envié un `resolve(snapshot.val())`, le envío el objeto entero a mi componente y lo recorro ahí. Gracias

Comment: @NicolsEstebanMoralesMorales marca la respuesta como aceptada, click en el check verde del costado de los números de votos de esta respuesta. Ayudarás a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas)